# In an AST Visitor, how can I know which node's property I am visiting?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm programming an AST Visitor (eclipse JDT).

An `EnumDeclaration` node contains the following structural properties:

`JAVADOC`, `MODIFIERS`, `NAME`, `SUPER_INTERFACE_TYPES`, `ENUM_CONSTANTS` and `BODY_DECLARATIONS`.

When I visit a child node of `EnumDeclaration` (a `SimpleName` node, for instance), is it possible to know which of the lists of nodes I'm visiting? Is it possible to differentiate?

I'd like to process a node differently, depending on whether I found it in `ENUM_CONSTANTS` or `BODY_DECLARATIONS`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. Explicitly visiting the nodes in the list (WITH `accept()`, not `visit()`). Something like (for visiting the super interfaces):

```
List<Type> superInterfaces = enumDecNode.superInterfaceTypes();
for( Type superInterface: superInterfaces)
    superInterface.accept( this);
```

Note that it is not possible to use:

```
    this.visit( superInterface);
```

because `Type` is an umbrella abstract class for which no `visit( Type node)` implementation exists.

This also forces the children of the nodes in the `superInterfaces` list to be visited as soon as their parent is visited. Problem solved.

On a side note, if you already process all the children of a node via these lists, you can forbid the visitor from re-visiting its children, by returning false.

Answer (score 1):

Your nodes should invoke corresponding methods.

```
MODIFIERS -> visitModifiers 
NAME -> visitNAME
```

and so on

Comment: @John Assymptoth, as it should be in visitor pattern. Show how you iterate over EnumDeclaration nodes.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand what you meant. My problem was in programming those methods.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative solution (thanks to Markus Keller @ eclipse JDT forum):

> Use "node.getLocationInParent() == EnumDeclaration.NAME_PROPERTY" or
>   other *_PROPERTY constants.
>
> Markus